# How can i invert my Regex matching results?

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have checked a lot of information about how can i invert my match..but unfortunatelly i coundnt be able to do it in for my problem. So..lets say i have this text :

> GS Sos_519 082_KO_Ge124222sshelden892 345

My goal is to match eveything that is not XYZ XYZ(numbers only). So i would like my results to be: 
`519 082892 345`.
Right now i've managed to do the opposite using this regex: `\d\d\d\s\d\d\d`. It matches exactly `519 082892 345` and now i have to invert it. I went to the logic to match what i want as results and then invert it..thinking it would be easyer that way..but i might be wrong. Matching everthing that is not in that specific format looks really complicated.
I've tryied to invert it using regex like this :

```
^(?:[\d\d\d\s\d\d\d].)*$
```

but unfortunately it does not match anything. I am new in regexes and i would really appreciate some help.
Thank you in advance !

Comment: tell us about the app you are plugging this regex into, and how varied are the strings in the file? is there a common format to them? it looks like you want to transform the string into another string, so you want to be using capture groups and a replace pattern, but consider when doing that, you must also match the portions of the line that won't be in the result, so you can exclude that group. `(.* )(stuffyouwant)(.*)` and your replace pattern woudl be `$1` or `\1` or whatever your platform uses to get `stuffyouwant`.

Comment: Note that `^` is ambiguous across platform implementations. in many languages it means start-of-string/line (so the counter part to $), but in others it means NOT (linux shell in particular does this, and uses `/` as its beginning and end token). what runtime will be interpreting your regex? in your case, try moving the final `.` outside of your group. '^(?:[\d\d\d\s\d\d\d]).*$' that way your file can end in `999 999`. otherwise it requires one more character after the number sequence.

Answer (score 2):

The strategy, here, is to try to match `3 digits spaces 3 digits` (i.e. `\d{3}\h+\d{3}`) and doesn't take care of them (i.e. don't remove), or, match any character and remove it.

The lookarounds `(?<!\d)` and `(?!\d)` is used to make sure we don't match 4 digit numbers.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<!\d)\d{3}\h+\d{3}(?!\d)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|.`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<!\d)     # negative lookbehind, make sure we haven't digit before
\d{3}       # 3 digits
\h+         # 1 or more horizontal spaces
\d{3}       # 3 digits
(?!\d)      # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't digit after
(*SKIP)     # skip this match
(*FAIL)     # force the match to fail
  |         # OR
.           # any character but newline
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]